# How to check whether that object has an event?

Tags: backbone.js

My example :

```
var object = {
    msg: 'context obj'
};
var object2 = {
    msg: 'other context obj2'
};
_.extend(Object.prototype, Backbone.Events);
object.on("alert:boom", function() {
    console.log("run " + this.msg);
}, object2);
object.on("all", function(eventName) {
    console.log('all');
});
object.trigger("alert:boom");
object.trigger("alert:riri"); //Why  called ALL ????
```

How to check whether that object has an event  ?
I hope for your help.

Comment: "All" called because it is "special event that fires for any triggered event". For more information you can check backbone documentation: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear if your question is "How to check whether that object has an event ?" or "//Why  called ALL ????" -- @AlexacderImra has answered the last one.

It is not recommended you check internal variables but it is very unlikely this will chage - the event array is `_events` so you can do:

```
if (myObject._events['myeventname'])
```

To check for a particular event, or:

```
if (myObject._events.length)
```

To check if there are any events.

It would be best to wrap that functionality in a function so that in the event it changes in  future versions of Backbone you only have to update the logic in one place.

Answer (score 1):

`all` is one of [built-in Backbone events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog).
`Callbacks bound to the special **all** event will be triggered when any event occurs, and are passed the name of the event as the first argument.`

So if you want to want to know when any event occurs, do like:

```
Object.on('all', function(eventName) {
    console.log('event [' + eventName + '] triggered');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify, check inside it.

```
JSON.stringify(object)
```